# AngularJS Ionic Logout: ReferenceError: $ionicHistory is not defined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement a logout in my code. This is what I have tried in my controller

```
.controller('menu', function($scope,$state) {
$scope.gotoLogouts = function() {
       // localStorage.clear();
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();

        $state.go("signin");
```

Then in my view I am calling it this way

```
<a menu-close ng-click="gotoLogouts()" style="color:black" ui-sref="entry" class="item"><i class="icon ion-power"></i> Logout</a>
```

When I click the log out state, I get this error History is not defined.

What am I doing wrong

Comment: How are you injecting `$ionicHistory`?

Comment: I am just calling it inside a function...  The function you see above

Comment: Yes, I can see that.  But, how are you actually injecting that service into your controller?

Comment: This is what I have in my controller ... .controller('menu', function($scope,$state) { .... correct me if am wrong

Comment: Add it to your question; comments don't do a good job of formatting code.

Answer (score 5):

From what I can see, you're not injecting the service into your controller correctly.

Take this approach, assuming that your module is defined elsewhere:

```
app.controller('menu', ['$scope', '$state', '$ionicHistory', function($scope, $state, $ionicHistory) {
    // logic here
}]);
```

Comment: So how do I call ionicHistory inside the controller?  at //logic here

Comment: Yes, you'd do all of your logic in the controller as before.  Nothing's changed here; you're just injecting the service you require.  This is more Angular-centric than Ionic-centric, though.

Comment: Please take of my complete code on controller.. The app crashes

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$injector/unpr?p0=%24ionicHistoryProvider%20%3C-%20%24ionicHistory

Comment: Again, **add it to your question.** I can't tell you what's going on with that injector erroring out since I don't know what specifically is causing it.  The above is the traditional way to inject services in Angular.

Comment: Okay... Will raise a new ticket